# mysql primary key starts with pattern

Tags: mysql, primary-key, unique, design-patterns

I have 2 tables books, mobiles in a Mysql database.

Tables structure being,

```
1. book_id|book_name  
2. mobile_id|mobile_name
```

A third table products with the following structure is also created,

1. product_id|product_name

Now, I want the book_id to start with a pattern in mysql.

For example,

```
book_ids -> 11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,110,111,112,...  
mobile_ids -> 21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,210,211,212,...
```

Now, in my products table I can have,

product_id -> 11,21,16,26, if this starts with pattern is not set,
then the problem would be,

product_id -> 1,1,6,6..its not unique.

How to handle this..?

### Edited stuff below:

So, are you meaning this..?

**category_table**

### category_id | category_name

*1 | books

2 | mobiles*

**book_table**

### book_id | book_name

*1 | da vinci code

2 | alchemist*

**mobile_table**

### mobile_id | mobile_name

*1 | nokia

2 | samsung*

**product_table**

### id | product_name | product_id | category_id

*1 | da vinci code | 1 | 1

2 | alchemist | 2 | 1

3 | nokia | 1 | 2

4 | samsuing | 2 | 2*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be duplicating information without a reason.

Just create a products table with:

```
id | name | type (e.g. 0 book, 1 mobile, etc) | price | ....
```

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about something like that. Of course if the table are more complex it may need some tweaking.